# How to display s3 image in collectionView get from API in swift

Tags: swift, api, amazon-s3, collectionview

I am a newbie in Swift. Now, I am developing an application which will get the data from API and display in Swift. I have store images in s3 as public at the backend and pass to Swift as a link by using API, e.g. https://example.com/20210501210101.png. I did much research on this topic online but I can't get suitable way to make my image display. Is there any way that can display the image get from s3 via link in Swift?

Message pass by API

```
{
   "success": true,
   "message": "Successfully retrieved image",
   "image_detail": [
       {
           "image": "https://example.com/20210501212429.png",
       }
   ]
}
```

I am displaying my image using collectionview and below are the example of my code

```
extension LandingPageViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return bannerDetailsItem.count
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = image_collection_view.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: 
indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
        let inputString = BASE_API_URL
        let splits = inputString.components(separatedBy: "api")
        let imageUrl:NSURL = NSURL(string: splits[0] + "storage/" + 
        bannerDetailsItem[indexPath.row].Image)!

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {

            let imageData:NSData = NSData(contentsOf: imageUrl as URL)!

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                cell.banner_image.image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)

            }
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - In Your  `ImageCollectionViewCell` create a function, to pass URL, let cell handle download part

```
@ImageCollectionViewCell:

func bind(imageUrlPath:String, indexPath:IndexPath) -> Void {

ImageCollectionViewCell.downloadImage(url:imageUrlPath) { (_image) in
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            
            if (self.tag == indexPath.row) {
                
                self. banner_image.image = _image;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2 - download image method from received URL using `URLSession`

```
@ImageCollectionViewCell:

class func downloadImage(url:String,onImage:@escaping ( _ image:UIImage?)-> Void) -> Void {
                
        if let imageURL = URL(string: url) {
            
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageURL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                
                if error != nil {
                    return
                }
                if let imageData = data {
                    onImage(UIImage(data: imageData));
                }
                
            });
            task.resume();
        }
    }
```

3 - finally in your controller, call/pass values

```
@LandingPageViewController:

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    cell.tag = indexPath.row;

    cell.bind(imageUrlPath: imageUrl, indexPath: indexPath)
        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the a good library for loading image from URL
[SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage)

You can install it via `CocoaPods` [CocoaPods.org](https://cocoapods.org)

After installing SDWebImage, you can load image by this example:

```
import SDWebImage

imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "http://www.example.com/path/to/image.jpg"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```